# Table to clean on setup script test

Tags: setup-script

Does anyone know what table or tables to clean when testing setup script?

I don't want to add an upgrade script, this is only for testing purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, you need to clean the same tables that your testing script is creating

Additionally, in `core_resource` table, set the version of your module back to what is was. Then clean cache and try again.

Delete the entry of your module from `core_resource` table if its the first version of your module